# In my visual studio 2013 while i build my solution it get failled but unable to see the error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

In my visual studio 2013 while i build my solution it gat failled but unable to see the error,can any one provide me the appropriate solution why this is happning.Instead i have restart my project several time but it was showing me same.

[image]

Hi all even if after clicking on error tab also it is not showing me the  errors.
[image]

Comment: In *Error List* window you are seeing the *Warnings* Tab currently. Change it to *Errors*.

Comment: Even if changing to error list it is not showing me the errors..

Comment: This is wrong. There currently are 2 errors that are hidden.

Comment: Do you see the Filter button in the top left? what happen if you click it?

Comment: Try going to Build, Clean Solution in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

[Click on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPEVU.png)

you have to remove filter by clicking on "0 of 2 errors"

Answer (score 0):

Remove those filters from error , and you will see errors

Answer (score 0):

This is not a VS Problem - it is you TELLING VISUAL STUDIO TO HIDE THE ERRORS.

On the tabs on top, click on the one with the errors. Then it will highlight and show the 2 errors it currently is hiding.

VS allows you to filter out errors and warnings. While I frequently also hide warnings - hiding the errors is not the smartest thing to do in most cases.

Comment: Hi Tom even if clicking on error tab also not showing me the errorlist.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "0 of 2 errors" and you will see...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing out your temporary .net files `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\{version of .net }\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root`

Answer (score 0):

> Do you see the Filter button in the top left? what happen if you click it? – hendryanw

That is the correct answer. Mostly probably you have filtering option "Current project" instead of "Entire solution". Pick "Entire solution" and you'd see errors.